# Enabling the virtualization feature in the virtual machine in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, virtualization

I set up a new virtual machine in the Google cloud. I also need to run Vmware Workstation in the virtual machine. But I could not find where to turn on the virtualization feature. I also could not access the BIOS.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQBmM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to run ESX hypervisor on top of GCE VM instance. Have a look at the documentation [Enabling nested virtualization for VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances):

> Nested virtualization adds support for [Intel VT-x](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-virtualization-developer-community) processor
> virtualization instructions to Compute Engine VMs. Using nested
> virtualization, you start a VM instance as normal on Compute Engine
> and then install a KVM-compatible hypervisor on the VM instance so you
> can run another VM instance on top of that hypervisor. You can use
> nested virtualization on any Linux VM instance running on a Haswell or
> newer platform. For other constraints, see the sub-section,
> [restrictions for nested virtualization](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances#restrictions).

and at the [Restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances#restrictions) section:

> - Nested virtualization is supported only for KVM-based hypervisors running on Linux instances. **Hyper-V, ESX, and Xen hypervisors are not
>   supported**.

**To solve your issue** you can use [Google Cloud VMware Engine](https://cloud.google.com/vmware-engine):

> Run your workloads in a native VMware environment—vSphere, vCenter,
> vSAN, NSX-T, and HCX—while benefiting from Google Cloud’s highly
> performant infrastructure to meet the needs of your enterprise
> workloads.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might looking for [Google Cloud VMware Engine](https://cloud.google.com/vmware-engine). using this GCP product you can move your VMware workload to GCP infra and will able to run your Workstation on it.